# jQuery iframe loading JavaScript content - context

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

```
var iframe = $('<iframe></iframe>').attr({id:'iframe', width:'200',height:'200', border:'1'});
$(document.body).append(iframe);
$('#iframe').attr({src:'doc-iframe.php'});

$('#iframe').load(function(){

     $('<div></div>', this.contentWindow.document).append(function(){
     $(this).append('<form name="test" id="test">
        <input name="name" value="Serban"><input type="submit"></form>
        <sc'+'ript>console.log(window); document.test.submit();</sc'+'ript>');
         });

     });
```

The code above is executed on the page http://test.local/doc.html
It tries to load some content into:

```
<iframe id="iframe" src="doc-iframe.php"></iframe>
```

The problem is that *document.test.submit()* is not executed inside the context of #iframe and document points to **doc.html** instead of **doc-iframe.php**.

How can I execute this code inside the context of #iframe?

***Consider that the HTML code inside append() is the result from an html AJAX response that I cannot control.***

Answer (score 0):

when you are working with an iFrame, with jQuery, you should always reference it like this:

```
$(this).contents().append(...)
```

I don't know if this helps, but your question is not very clear...

Comment: In side append you have 'document.form1.submit()' and this triggers document.form1 is undefined, because the context is the actual page not the iframe. This is my problem.

Comment: so, if the $(this) refers to the page, try $(this).find('#iframe').contents().append(...)

Comment: Try to run the code replacing doc-iframe.php with an empty html file. You'll see the error. I tried every suggested solution, but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Use the context selector to specify the iframe as the target:

```
document.title = $("form#test", frames[0].document).submit();
```

Use an equality check to identify the context node:

```
console.assert($(this).get(0) === $(frames[0]).get(0), "not the iframe", $(this).get(0) );
```

**References**

- [Firefox Web Console: The Command Line Interpreter - Helper Commands](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Web_Console/The_command_line_interpreter#Helper_commands)
- [Chromium Command Line API Reference](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/commandline-api)
- [Opera Dragonfly commandtransformer.js](https://github.com/operasoftware/dragonfly/blob/master/src/repl/commandtransformer.js#L267)
- [F12 developer tools console API methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/dn265020)